# Using arrays in Excel

Tags: arrays, excel, find

I have one cell that contains the following information:

```
door,
chair,
lock,
bed,
```

I want to take each word (so look for the comma) and use that word in a vlookup to get a price and then put the price in another field.

I can get this to work for the very first find of the comma, however I'm not able to make the find function cycle through each word as the instance number won't increment (and I can't figure out how to do that).

With google sheets arrayformula does this perfectly but I'm stuck in trying to get excel to do it.

The end result should be:

```
59.99
29.99
39.99
49.99
```

Here the formula I have so far:

```
=vlookup(left(cell),find(",",cell)-1),vlookuprange,3,false)&char(10)
```

I've tried turning into an array with `ctrl-shift-enter` but I'm missing something that I'm not getting.

Comment: can you show us the table ?

Comment: You want the results in one cell?

Comment: yes I want the contents in one cell... so use all the words (delimited by comma) to vlookup the price and then have the price all in one cell line by line.. hope that makes sense...  not sure how to paste a table.. (new to this)

Comment: @Lorie Then you will need to do one of the first two options I gave in my answer.  Unfortunately, until Office 365 Excel there is no native way to do it, You could use the third method and concatenate the results into one cell as a second step.  But, there is no way with older Excels to do what you want without vba in one step.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a subscription to Office 365 Excel then you can use TEXTJOIN as an array formula:

```
 =TEXTJOIN(CHAR(10),TRUE,IFERROR(LOOKUP(TRIM(CLEAN(MID(SUBSTITUTE($A$1,",",REPT(" ",999)),(ROW(INDIRECT("1:" & LEN(A1)- LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,",",""))))-1)*999+1,999))),$D$1:$D$4,$E$1:$E$4),""))
```

Being an array formula it needs to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.  If done correctly then Excel will put `{}` around the formula.

Another requirement is for the data in the lookup space to be sorted alphabetically in the lookup range.

[image]

---

If you do not you will need to use vba ***OR*** get the results in different cells.

---

VBA method (Results like above):

Use this UDF to mimic the TEXTJOIN().  Put this code in a module attached to the workbook, then use the formula above as instructed.

```
Function TEXTJOIN(delim As String, skipblank As Boolean, arr)
    Dim d As Long
    Dim c As Long
    Dim arr2()
    Dim t As Long, y As Long
    t = -1
    y = -1
    If TypeName(arr) = "Range" Then
        arr2 = arr.Value
    Else
        arr2 = arr
    End If
    On Error Resume Next
    t = UBound(arr2, 2)
    y = UBound(arr2, 1)
    On Error GoTo 0

    If t >= 0 And y >= 0 Then
        For c = LBound(arr2, 1) To UBound(arr2, 1)
            For d = LBound(arr2, 1) To UBound(arr2, 2)
                If arr2(c, d) <> "" Or Not skipblank Then
                    TEXTJOIN = TEXTJOIN & arr2(c, d) & delim
                End If
            Next d
        Next c
    Else
        For c = LBound(arr2) To UBound(arr2)
            If arr2(c) <> "" Or Not skipblank Then
                TEXTJOIN = TEXTJOIN & arr2(c) & delim
            End If
        Next c
    End If
    TEXTJOIN = Left(TEXTJOIN, Len(TEXTJOIN) - Len(delim))
End Function
```

---

Different cells method:

Put this in the first cell:

```
=VLOOKUP(TRIM(CLEAN(MID(SUBSTITUTE($A$1,",",REPT(" ",999)),(ROW(1:1)-1)*999+1,999))),D:E,2,FALSE)
```

And copy down:

[image]

Comment: this is great... but the data that I'm using for the vlookup are all in one cell and I want the results to also be all in one cell...

Comment: @Lorie and I gave you two way to accomplish that.  There are three different methods to do this.  One of the first two return what you want.

Comment: that worked.. I would never have come up with that in a million years...   the only thing that didn't work was the Char(10) didn't do the line feed so the answer I got looked like 59.9929.9939.9949.99 instead of the price each on a seperate line in the same cell.

Comment: You need to wrap the text.  With the cell highlighted, click on Wrap text on the Home tab @Lorie Pleas also consider marking as correct by clicking on the check mark by the answer.

Comment: not sure if you will see this but I have an additional question.. First thanks for all your help, this formula has enabled me to learn so much more about CSE and now I'm doing them regularly.  My question regarding this formula, in the cell A1 where I have the data that is going to be looked up individually, is there a limit to the number of items..  i currently have one with 30 items and it works great.. but the 31st item won't work... gives me a #value in the first substitute... I've tried everything I can think of..

Comment: There is probably a character limitation.  At this point, writing a custom vba subroutine would be better.

Comment: thank you.. that's what I thought...  i'll have to do another work around for it...